"@clerk/nextjs/server"' has no exported member named 'clerkMiddleware'
I am working on Nextjs 14 with typescript and I am trying to use clerk for authentication and authorization. When I created the app using the clerk docs I was said to write the following code in middleware.ts
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({});

export const config = {
    matcher: ["/((?!.+.[w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};


Then after sometime when I went to apply protected routes in the clerk documentation I found :
This method is now deprecated. Please use clerkMiddleware() instead.

the docs: https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/auth-middleware
When I wrote this in my middleware.ts I get the error in the title:
'"@clerk/nextjs/server"' has no exported member named 'clerkMiddleware'. Did you mean 'WithClerkMiddleware'?ts(2724)

I have also used
npm i clerk@latest

How should I solve the error

It looks like there is a typo in the package name you're trying to install. To resolve the issue, you should update to version 5.0.0 or newer, which includes the clerkMiddleware function. You can update the package by running the following command in your terminal:
npm i @clerk/nextjs@latest   


try using this version of clerk:     "@clerk/nextjs": "^4.29.12" with the middleware that u wrote. it should work. I am using the same in my project.

Clerk now has a Core-2 (from version 5 onwards)
There is an upgrade guide here: https://clerk.com/docs/upgrade-guides/core-2/nextjs
With this installed: "@clerk/nextjs": "^5.0.3", I can now use these methods without errors.
import { clerkMiddleware, createRouteMatcher } from '@clerk/nextjs/server';


reference link: https://clerk.com/docs/references/nextjs/clerk-middleware
import { clerkMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs/server";

